# Fail to callback authentication with 'github' when logging in using GitHub Authentication for SonarQube

Tags: github, sonarqube

I am setting up SonarQube 6.2 and want to use the GitHub Authentication for SonarQube to authenticate with SonarQube to allow users to sign-in to SonarQube using there GitHub login.

When logging in the first time using the GitHub OAuth button I get redirected to GitHub, I enter my credentials and am redirected back to my SonarQube instance to https://sonarqube.xxx/sessions/unauthorized saying You're not authorized to access this page. Please contact the administrator.

When looking at the log file I see the following exception

```html
2017.04.19 09:52:18 ERROR web[AVuFEY20neO0dCgEAAOc][o.s.s.a.AuthenticationError] Fail to callback authentication with 'github'
com.github.scribejava.core.exceptions.OAuthException: Response body is incorrect. Can't extract a 'access_token=([^&]+)' from this: 'error=bad_verification_code&error_description=The+code+passed+is+incorrect+or+expired.&error_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.github.com%2Fv3%2Foauth%2F%23bad-verification-code'
 at com.github.scribejava.core.extractors.OAuth2AccessTokenExtractor.extractParameter(OAuth2AccessTokenExtractor.java:61)
 at com.github.scribejava.core.extractors.OAuth2AccessTokenExtractor.extract(OAuth2AccessTokenExtractor.java:41)
 at com.github.scribejava.core.extractors.OAuth2AccessTokenExtractor.extract(OAuth2AccessTokenExtractor.java:13)
 at com.github.scribejava.core.oauth.OAuth20Service.sendAccessTokenRequestSync(OAuth20Service.java:37)
 at com.github.scribejava.core.oauth.OAuth20Service.getAccessToken(OAuth20Service.java:56)
 at org.sonarsource.auth.github.GitHubIdentityProvider.onCallback(GitHubIdentityProvider.java:119)
 at org.sonarsource.auth.github.GitHubIdentityProvider.callback(GitHubIdentityProvider.java:107)
 at org.sonar.server.authentication.OAuth2CallbackFilter.doFilter(OAuth2CallbackFilter.java:71)
 at org.sonar.server.platform.web.MasterServletFilter$GodFilterChain.doFilter(MasterServletFilter.java:126)
 at org.sonar.server.platform.web.MasterServletFilter.doFilter(MasterServletFilter.java:95)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
 at org.sonar.server.user.UserSessionFilter.doFilter(UserSessionFilter.java:83)
 at org.sonar.server.user.UserSessionFilter.doFilter(UserSessionFilter.java:66)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
 at org.sonar.server.platform.web.SecurityServletFilter.doHttpFilter(SecurityServletFilter.java:73)
 at org.sonar.server.platform.web.SecurityServletFilter.doFilter(SecurityServletFilter.java:49)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
 at org.sonar.server.platform.web.RoutesFilter.doFilter(RoutesFilter.java:55)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
 at org.sonar.server.platform.web.requestid.RequestIdFilter.doFilter(RequestIdFilter.java:63)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
 at org.sonar.server.platform.web.RootFilter.doFilter(RootFilter.java:62)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
 at ch.qos.logback.access.tomcat.LogbackValve.invoke(LogbackValve.java:256)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

When clicking the 'home' link and clicking the GitHub OAuth button again I am successfully authenticated and can enter SonarQube as my GitHub user.

In SonarQube I have entered:
General 
1. Changed Server base URL to my https domain https://sonarqube.some-domain.xx
GitHub settings
1. Organizations
2. Client Secret
3. Client ID
4. Changed Login generation strategy to Same as GitHub login

I am using NGinX as a reverse proxy to redirect from https to http SonarQube url and have configured a p12 certificate on the https url.

Does anyone know how to fix  this issue?

Comment: Which version of the GitHub Authentication plugin are you using ?

Comment: We are using version 1.3 of the GitHub Authentication plugin with SonarQube 6.2.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue with SonarQube 9.1. If you have reached this state, then most likely everything else is set up correctly.

The problem is on the Sonar side. If your Sonar web server domain is https://sonar.some-domain.xx, the same domain name should be written in the *Server base URL* variable (Key: `sonar.core.serverBaseURL`.)

So on your Sonar web page go to **Administration** → **Configuration** → **General** → **Server base URL** and set it to https://sonar.some-domain.xx.